# What is the higher dimensional generalisation of the angular momentum ladder operators?

Tags: operators, angular-momentum

While the higher dimensional generalization of the angular momentum operator from $\vec L = \vec r\times\vec p$ in 3D to

\begin{align}
  L_{ij} &= r_i p_j - r_j p_i
\end{align}

(and e.g. $L_z = L_{xy}$ in 3D) in $d$ dimensions is pretty straightforward, and it's square is then

$$L_d^2 := \frac12 \sum_{i,j=1}^d (L_{ij})^2 \text{ and } [L_d^2,L_{ij}]=0,$$

I couldn't find any information on generalized ladder operators.

Of course since in $d$ dimensions the Eigenbase is defined by a set of $d-1$ Eigenvalues $|l_2,...,l_d\rangle$ (with $l_2=m$ usually and $l_3$ labelled just $l$ in 3D), there would be multiple ladder operators, which should be possible to define iteratively with increasing dimensions, just like the recurrence equation [derived here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364789/163) for the $L_d^2$:

\begin{align}
  L_d^2 &= \frac1{s_d^{d-1}}\partial_d(s_d^{d-1}\partial_d) + \frac1{s_d^2} L_{d-1}^2 \quad\text{with } s_d:=\sin\theta_d,\ \partial_d := \frac\partial{\partial\theta_d}
\end{align}

where $\theta_d$ is the $d^\text{th}$ angle (actually $(d-1)^\text{th}$ but let's just define $\theta_1\equiv0$ for less index confusion).

The latest dimension's ladder operators $L_d^\pm$ would obey similar commutator relations as the 3D ones $L_3^\pm = L_x \pm i L_y = e^{\pm i\phi}(\partial_\theta \pm i\cot\theta \partial\phi)$ - which are $[L_z,L_3^\pm] = \pm L_3^\pm$ (let's have $\hbar=1$) and $[L_3^+, L_3^-] = 2L_z$, but since in higher dimensions there is no "$L_z$" I'm not entirely sure what to put there...

Note that $L_3^\pm L_3^\mp = L_3^2 - L_z^2 \pm L_z$, suggesting

\begin{align}
   L_d^2 &= \frac12\{L_d^+,L_d^-\} + L_{d-1}^2.
\end{align}

One possibility of replacing $L_z$ in the ladder commutators would be using $\sqrt{L_{d-1}^2}$ (though that probably makes little sense or might yield unnecessary spinors), another one would be $L_{d-1}^\pm$ somehow.

I've thought of two approaches next:

A) Assume $L_d^+ = \sum_{i,j} c_{ij} L_{ij}$ (and $L_d^- = (L_d^+)^\dagger$) and calculate the coefficients using the relation for $L_d^2$ plus figure out sensible commutator relations

B) Try something like $L_d^\pm = e^{\pm i\alpha\theta_{d-1}}(\partial_d \pm i\beta\cot^\gamma\theta_d\partial_{d-1})$ for proper constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ to factor $L_d^2 - L_{d-1}^2$ and see what commutator relations that yields.

But before I delve any deeper and reinvent the wheel, has this really not been published before?

Comment: Lookup the Cartan Weyl basis of $so(d)$.

Comment: Thanks @ConnorBehan, I'll have a look - found https://webhome.weizmann.ac.il/home/fnkirson/Alg17/Notes/10.Cartan-Weyl_basis.pdf of interest, and https://webhome.weizmann.ac.il/home/fnkirson/Alg17/Notes/10.Cartan-Weyl_basis.pdf